# ng-model does not work after $(element).clone()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, angularjs-ng-model

I have a directive that clone object while drag and drop.

```
app.directive('ironplayDraggableBox', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".preview",
        helper: function(){
          $new_el = $(this).clone();
          return $compile($new_el)(scope);
        },
        handle: ".drag",
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

But when I drag the DOM element with HTML code like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="align">{{align}}
```

`ng-model` stops work completely.

Could you suggest how to implement proper dom element clone with angular directives inside?

Here is the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OJ1a5VyqQq9EpXP7AfpA?p=preview
The goal in plunker to have text align select working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your helper clone is not the one being placed in the HTML at the end. You can take the final element from the sortable element's `stop` event, and compile it (you need to inject $compile to that directive):

```
stop: function(e, ui) {
  $compile(ui.item)(scope);
}
```

In order for the model to take affect you also need to change the h3 from class to ng-class

```
<h3 ng-class="align" contenteditable="true">Hello</h3>
```

Also notice you can create your draggable element with a new scope so each one will have a different state.

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9xlHUelcvmI8u8WE8cE?p=preview).